# Access Yes/No Field Data Type Mismatch with Boolean Value

Tags: vba, parameters, ms-access-2007, ado, type-mismatch

Using excel VBA, I'm trying to execute a parametised query using ADO with Access 2007.

The field in Access is defined as `Yes/No` and the parameters specified as below:

```
If UF_Main.obCRTN.Value Then
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p18", adBoolean, adParamInput, , False)
Else
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p18", adBoolean, adParamInput, , True)
End If
```

*Note that the control `obCRTN` is an `OptionButton` and the if statement works correctly.*

When I try and execute the query however, a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` error is thrown. When removing the above parameters from the query and code, the query executes fine.

According to the [documentation for ADO on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_datatypes.asp), the `DataType Enum` for `Yes/No` in Access should be `adBoolean`.

Can anyone help with why this error is being thrown?

Comment: Are you sure you have the parameters in the correct order? It does not matter what you call them, the parameters must be in the order in which they appear in the query.

Comment: @Fionnuala Yes definitely in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, I had to execute the query directly in Access (which produced a strange result and didn't actually add the record).

I tried again directly in Access and the query worked. I then tried from the macro in VBA and it executed no problem.

*Strange*